# Getting error while installing Matlab R2016a

Tags: matlab

The error message is:

> Could not complete Activation because the License File could not be written to disk.
>
> You might not have write permission on the License File or the folder. /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/licenses/trial_0_R2016a.lic
> See your System Administrator for assistance. The specific error message text is:
> /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/licenses/trial_0_R2016a.lic (No such file or directory).

I installed MatLab using the following command from terminal:

```
$ sudo R2016a_glnxa64/install Matlab
```

GUI opens and the installation is successful.
Then using the following command:

```
$ sudo cp -av libcufft.so.7.5.18 libmwservices.so /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/
```

I'm getting an error as no such dir exist.
Then using:

```
$ sudo cp -av libcufft.so.7.5.18 libmwservices.so
```

process completed!
Then using:

```
$ sudo /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/matlab
```

GUI opening, specifying the path to `license.dat` file, then next and the pop up appears with the said error.

Comment: you may need to use sudo for the script or package you are trying to install. Is it a .deb?

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that you do not have permission to write to the licenses folder.

First change to the directory with the activation client.
`cd /usr/local/bin/glnxa64`
Then run the activation as follows:
`sudo -E ./activate_matlab.sh`

Source:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101497-why-do-i-get-an-error-could-not-complete-activation-because-the-license-file-could-not-be-written-t?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com